# Rotor Current and Torque Producing Current in Induction Motor

Tags: current, motor, induction-motor, torque, electric-machine

Is rotor current of an Induction motor always same with torque producing current?

In torque equation of Induction motor, there is also one factor called rotor power factor. if rotor current and torque current are not always same, how we get current drawn by motor by vector sum of magnetizing current & torque current ? I mean rotor current may be bigger than torque producing current due to power factor and we may get wrong result if we just make vector sum of torque current and magnetiziation current.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both the currents are the same. The torque developed is proportional to current induced in the rotor.

Comment: Why then we invented wound rotor induction motors?